# Convert JSON to POJO having Json property as jsonObject having diffrent property

Tags: java, json, jackson, fasterxml

I have new requirement, I am creating REST API which has dynamic request (actions) and I want to convert that JSON request to POJO, I know how to convert JSON to POJO where key's are same, but not sure what to do when there are different content on objects.

My Json is as follow.

```
{
  "name":"Workflow",
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "EDIT_PROPERTY",
      "payload": {
        "name": "city",
        "value": "Pune"
      }
    },
    {
      "name":"SEND_EMAIL",
      "payload":{
        "from":"no-reply@yaho.com",
        "to":"alpesh@yahoo.com",
        "subject":"Try email",
        "body":"content"
      }
    },
    {
      "name":"CREATE_TASK",
      "payload":{
        "user":1,
        "type":"call",
        "status":"open",
        "note":"This is  note content"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see actions are set of Objects which has name and payload, now  payload has different fields, I have predefined names. and each payload under action has predefined keys as you see.

I want to convert this to POJO something like

```
class Workflow{
    String name;
    Set<Action> actions;
}

class Action {
    String name;
    //What to add as payload
}
```

Thanks

Alpesh

Comment: May be store payload as Map<String, Object> ?

Comment: But when I use Object then it is not type safe.

Comment: @Alpesh Jikadra Which JSON library did you use? I tested it with `Jackson` (JDK 1.8) to deserialize field `payload` to `Map<String, Object>` as @SKumar commented and it works fine without any error.

Comment: Are you ok with Map<String,String> or you want to retain the data types ?

Comment: @SKumar, Yes I want to retain data types.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do :

JSON to POJO model :

```
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Event {
    public String name;
    public List<Action> actions;


    @Data
    public static class Action {
        public String name;
        Map<String, Object> payload;
    }


}

public class TestJson {

    private static String json = "{\n" +
            "  \"name\":\"Workflow\",\n" +
            "  \"actions\": [\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "      \"name\": \"EDIT_PROPERTY\",\n" +
            "      \"payload\": {\n" +
            "        \"name\": \"city\",\n" +
            "        \"value\": \"Pune\"\n" +
            "      }\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "      \"name\":\"SEND_EMAIL\",\n" +
            "      \"payload\":{\n" +
            "        \"from\":\"no-reply@yaho.com\",\n" +
            "        \"to\":\"alpesh@yahoo.com\",\n" +
            "        \"subject\":\"Try email\",\n" +
            "        \"body\":\"content\"\n" +
            "      }\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "      \"name\":\"CREATE_TASK\",\n" +
            "      \"payload\":{\n" +
            "        \"user\":1,\n" +
            "        \"type\":\"call\",\n" +
            "        \"status\":\"open\",\n" +
            "        \"note\":\"This is  note content\"\n" +
            "      }\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "  ]\n" +
            "}";

    @SneakyThrows
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Event event = objectMapper.readValue(json, Event.class);
        System.out.println(event);

    }


}
```

When debugging, you'll notice that our objects have been filled accordingly:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbGLT.png]

Comment: With this, I might end up by adding too many fields under Payload class, which is not required for other Entities. i.e. EDIT_PROPERTY type. in future also I might has new type of payload for new action.

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra ok, in that case, i have updated the payload as map i.e Map<String, Object> payload; also updated the answer and it working without any issues.

Comment: Instead of Map<String, Object>, Can I use some kind of inheritance so I can use base class instead of Map ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, generally, I prefer any solution that does not involve **Component Annotations**.  This is my own personal preference because eliminating `constructors` and method `parameters` is usually a giant headache.  This is based on 1999 - 2006 Java Programming experience.  If you have a need to dynamically generate classes and `constructors` or `getters`, then you may easily ignore or delete this answer.  For me, **JSON Parsing** is practice right now.

In this posted answer, I have used the older Java **JSON Library** whose **JavaDoc** may be viewed here: [`javax.json.*`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/package-summary.html).  Here is my solution. It requires / expects that you write:

- Your own `toString()` methods for your **JSON Data Classes**
- Your own ***retrieve operations***

The following code has output, and that is included at the end of this post.  Usually I include a lot of Code Documentation.  However, when the code is **strictly parsing data**, the code itself is usually so legible that more comments would clutter the **retrieve** and the **`toString()`** operations, so I have left them as is.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.json.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Messages
{
    public abstract static class Action
    {
        public final String name;
        public Action(String name) { this.name=name; }
    }

    public static class EditProperty extends Action
    {
        public final String propName, propValue;

        public EditProperty(String name, String value)
        { super("EDIT_PROPERTY"); this.propName=name; this.propValue=value; }

        public String toString()
        { 
            return 
                "Action:   " + name         + '\n' + 
                "Name:     " + propName     + '\n' +
                "Value:    " + propValue    + '\n';
        }
    }

    public static class SendEmail extends Action
    {
        public final String from, to, subject, body;

        public SendEmail(String from, String to, String subject, String body)
        { super("SEND_EMAIL"); this.from=from; this.to=to; this.subject=subject; this.body=body; }

        public String toString()
        {
            return
                "Action:   "    + name      + '\n' +
                "From:     "    + from      + '\n' +
                "To:       "    + to        + '\n' +
                "Subject:  "    + subject   + '\n' +
                "Body:     "    + body      + '\n';
        }
    }

    public static class CreateTask extends Action
    {
        public final int user;
        public final String type, status, note;

        public CreateTask(int user, String type, String status, String note)
        { super("CREATE_TASK"); this.user=user; this.type=type; this.status=status; this.note=note; }

        public String toString()
        {
            return
                "Action:   " + name     + '\n' +
                "User:     " + user     + '\n' +
                "Type:     " + type     + '\n' +
                "Status:   " + status   + '\n' +
                "Note:     " + note     + '\n';
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException
    {
        Vector<Action>  actions     = new Vector<>();
        Reader          r           = new FileReader("in.json");

        JsonArray       actionList  = Json
            .createReader(r)
            .readObject()
            .getJsonArray("actions");

        for (JsonObject actionObj : actionList.getValuesAs(JsonObject.class))
        {
            JsonObject  payload = actionObj.getJsonObject("payload");
            Action      action  = null;

            switch (actionObj.getString("name"))
            {
                case "EDIT_PROPERTY"    :   action = new EditProperty(
                                                payload.getString("name"),
                                                payload.getString("value")
                                            ); break;
                case "SEND_EMAIL"       :   action = new SendEmail(
                                                payload.getString("from"),
                                                payload.getString("to"),
                                                payload.getString("subject"),
                                                payload.getString("body")
                                            ); break;
                case "CREATE_TASK"      :   action = new CreateTask(
                                                payload.getInt("user"),
                                                payload.getString("type"),
                                                payload.getString("status"),
                                                payload.getString("note")
                                            ); break;
            }
            
            actions.add(action);
        }
        
        for (Action action : actions) System.out.println(action);
    }
}
```

The class and inner-classes above would produce this output when invoked at the command line:

```
@cloudshell:~$ java Messages 
Action:   EDIT_PROPERTY
Name:     city
Value:    Pune

Action:   SEND_EMAIL
From:     no-reply@yaho.com
To:       alpesh@yahoo.com
Subject:  Try email
Body:     content

Action:   CREATE_TASK
User:     1
Type:     call
Status:   open
Note:     This is  note content
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you show is actually a list of one object type;
specifically, the payload is just a Map of String to Object.

Once you parse the JSON,
your code will need to process each "different" payload type
based on the payload type.

Here is some sample code:

```java
public class BlamMessage
{
    private String name;
    private Map<String, Object> payload;

    ...
}

public class MessageHolder
{
    @JsonProperty("actions")
    private List<BlamMessage> messageList;

    private String name;

    ...
}
```